# How to track state for OpenID Connect in Safari IFrame with ITP?

Tags: safari, csrf, openid-connect, lti

Recent specifications such as LTI 1.3 use (IdP-initiated) OpenID Connect to authenticate tools. In LTI, these tools typically run in an iframe on a different domain. The theory is that the entire authentication flow is 'just' a 3-step back-and-forth of browser redirects.

To avoid CSRF, it is recommended to track a state parameter in a session with OpenID connect. However, Safari has different hoops that need to be jumped through before any storage is available in an iframe: Storage may need to be requested (after user interaction), a cookie needs to have been previously set in top-level context, ...

All solutions I can think of to initiate an OpenID connect from within an IFrame (with CSRF protection) requires lots of code and checks, including several back-and-forths between backend (to set http-only session) and frontend (to check and request cookie storage). I can't imagine that a standard as recent as LTI 1.3 would require so much complexity just to get it working, so I was wondering if there were 'recommended' approaches to doing OpenID connect from within an iframe with a state parameter.

Comment: It might be worth mentioning that Canvas' current solution to this problem sounds a lot like the complicated ones you were able to come up with, except that it also uses an (I think) undocumented and nonstadard postMessage api. Here's the link: https://community.canvaslms.com/t5/Developers-Group/Safari-13-1-and-LTI-Integration/ba-p/273051

Comment: @GrahamLeach-Krouse Thanks, that's an interesting link. Another solution I came up with (but haven't tested yet) is to detect when running in an iframe, and in that case show a button to open a top-level popup that does the auth flow, and postMessage back when finished. The advantage is that this simplifies the code and flow, and works around other issues such as webkit not working without ever having a first party cookie. The disadvantage is that this now requires a button on every browser when running in an iframe, instead of just on ITP browsers (only Safari for now?)

Answer (score 0):

1EdTech now provide a specification to address just this - LTI OIDC Login with LTI Client Side postMessages. Yep, it's a mouthful. Of course, the platform needs to provide support for this spec, since it's using the platform as a kind of storage via postMessages. This and other specs can be found on the main [LTI page](https://www.imsglobal.org/activity/learning-tools-interoperability).

The [Client side postMessage specification](https://www.imsglobal.org/spec/lti-cs-oidc/v0p1) describes the process as follows:

> - Platform: Send an OIDC Initiation signal
> - Tool: Determine whether you can use cookies
> - Tool: Send message to store state & nonce
> - Platform: Store data and respond
> - Tool: Wait for response and continue with OIDC flow
> - Platform: Continue with OIDC Auth Response back to tool
> - Tool: Verify state & nonce match

and also provides some js examples describing how to put and get your state and nonce data in the platform store:

> 3.1 JS Example: Sending a put_data message to platform
>
> The tool will send a put_data message like this:
>
> ```
> let platformOrigin = new URL(platformOIDCLoginURL).origin;
> let frameName = getQueryParam("lti_storage_target");
> let parent = window.parent || window.opener;
> let targetFrame = frameName === "_parent" ? parent : parent.frames[frameName];
>
> targetFrame.postMessage({
>        "subject": "lti.put_data",
>        "message_id": messageId,
>        "key": "state_<state_id>",
>        "value": "<state_id>"
>      } , platformOrigin )
>
>
> targetFrame.postMessage({
>        "subject": "lti.put_data",
>        "message_id": messageId,
>        "key": "nonce_<nonce_value>",
>        "value": "<nonce_value>"
>      } , platformOrigin )
> ```

> 3.2 JS example: Listen for put_data.response
>
> ```
> window.addEventListener('message', function (event) {
>     // This isn't a message we're expecting
>     if (typeof event.data !== "object"){
>         return;
>     }
>
>     // Validate it's the response type you expect
>     if (event.data.subject !== "lti.put_data.response") {
>         return;
>     }
>
>     // Validate the message id matches the id you sent
>     if (event.data.message_id !== messageId) {
>         // this is not the response you're looking for
>         return;
>     }
>
>     // Validate that the event's origin is the same as the derived platform origin
>     if (event.origin !== platformOrigin) {
>         return;
>     }
>
>     // handle errors
>     if (event.data.error){
>         // handle errors
>         console.log(event.data.error.code)
>         console.log(event.data.error.message)
>         return;
>     }
>
>     // It's the response we expected
>     // The state and nonce values were successfully stored, redirect to Platform
>     redirect_to_platform(platformOIDCLoginURL); 
> });
> ```

> 3.3 JS Example: Sending get_data message to platform
>
> The tool will send a get_data message like this:
>
> ```
> let platformOrigin = new URL(platformOIDCLoginURL).origin;
> let frameName = getQueryParam("lti_storage_target");
> let parent = window.parent || window.opener;
> let targetFrame = frameName === "_parent" ? parent : parent.frames[frameName];
>
> targetFrame.postMessage({
>         "subject": "lti.get_data",
>         "message_id": messageId,
>         "key": "state_<state_id>",
>       } , platformOrigin )
>
>
> targetFrame.postMessage({
>         "subject": "lti.get_data",
>         "message_id": messageId,
>         "key": "nonce_<nonce_value>",
>       } , platformOrigin )
> ```

> 3.4 JS example: Listen for get_data response
>
> ```
> window.addEventListener('message', function (event) {
>     // This isn't a message we're expecting
>     if (typeof event.data !== "object"){
>         return;
>     }
>
>     // Validate it's the response type you expect
>     if (event.data.subject !== "lti.get_data.response") {
>         return;
>     }
>
>     // Validate the message id matches the id you sent
>     if (event.data.message_id !== messageId) {
>         // this is not the response you're looking for
>         return;
>     }
>
>     // Validate that the event's origin is the same as the derived platform origin
>     if (event.origin !== platformOrigin) {
>         return;
>     }
>
>     // handle errors
>     if (event.data.error){
>         // handle errors
>         console.log(event.data.error.code)
>         console.log(event.data.error.message)
>         return;
>     }
>
>     // It's the response we expected
>     // The state and nonce values were successfully fetched, validate them
>     ajax_with_values_or_redirect_again() 
> });
> ```